# Как осуществить слияние k сортированных списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Даны k отсортированных в порядке неубывания массивов натуральных чисел, каждое из которых не превосходит 100. Требуется построить результат их слияния: отсортированный в порядке неубывания массив, содержащий все элементы исходных k массивов.

Длина каждого массива не превосходит 10 ⋅ k.

Постарайтесь, чтобы решение работало за время k ⋅ log(k) ⋅ n, если считать, что входные массивы имеют длину n.

## Формат ввода

Первая строка входного файла содержит единственное число k, k ≤ 1024.

Каждая из следующих k строк описывает по одному массиву. Первое число каждой строки равняется длине соответствующего массива, оставшиеся числа этой строки описывают значения элементов этого же массива. Элементы массивов являются натуральными числами и не превосходят 100.

## Формат вывода

Выходной файл должен содержать отсортированный в порядке неубывания массив, содержащий все элементы исходных массивов.

## Пример

### Ввод

`4
6 2 26 64 88 96 96
4 8 20 65 86
7 1 4 16 42 58 61 69
1 84`

### Вывод

`1 2 4 8 16 20 26 42 58 61 64 65 69 84 86 88 96 96`

Ограничение по времени выполнение скрипта 1 сек. для любого теста, ограничение по используемой памяти: 10 МБ

Вот мой код:

```
import sys

int_str = ''
n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
for i in range(int(n)):
    s = sys.stdin.readline().strip() + ' '
    count = int(s[:s.find(' ')])
    p, j = 0, 0
    for j in range(s.__len__()):
        if s[j] == ' ':
            p += 1
        if p == count+1:
            break
    int_str += s[s.find(' '):j]
    del (s,)

for i in sorted(int_str.lstrip().split(' '), key=lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else 0):
    print(i, end=" ")
```

## Ещё один вариант

```
import sys

n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
int_list = []
for i in range(n):
    input = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    data = list(map(int, input.split()))
    input = None
    n = data[0]
    a = data[1:n+1]
    int_list.extend(a)
    data = None

int_list.sort()

for li in int_list:
    sys.stdout.write(str(li) + ' ')
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

## Гномья сортировка

```
import sys

int_list = []
t = [0] * 101
n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
for i in range(int(n)):
    s = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    try:
        num = int(s[:s.find(' ')])
    except ValueError:
        continue
    for index, value in enumerate(s.split(' ')):
        if index == 0:
            continue
        elif index == num + 1:
            break
        try:
            t[int(value)] += 1
        except ValueError:
            pass
    del s

res = []
for i in range(101):
    res += [i] * t[i]

for r in res:
    print(r, end=' ')
```

`Memory Limit и Time Limit близко`

Comment: А в чем проблема то? Сделайте за k*k*n потом подскажем как ускорить.

Comment: проблема в том, что при любом решении или превышаю лимит памяти, либо времени выполнения скрипта

Comment: Вообще если цель просто сдать - искать по "сортировка подсчетом".

Comment: проблема ваших решений в том, что вы никак не используете ни пункт "k отсортированных списков" ни пункт "числа меньше 100". Безусловно то что вы написали имеет сложность `n log n` как минимум и не успевает.

Comment: Как ещё можно ускорить последний вариант?)

Comment: Ну например сразу печатать без создания доп массива. Это память. А по скорости - чтение слишком большое. В питоне нету более быстрого способа? Чем читать всю строку, потом искать пробел.

Comment: Это задача F из Яндекс.Интервью. У их тестовой системы жёсткие лимиты на время / память: что на C++ решение даётся 1 секунда, что на C#, что на python. Делал решение на C++ через сортировку подсчётом. Время 319ms, память 380.00Kb. Абсолютно такое же решение на C# не проходит по времени: 1.092s. Для сравнения можно вспомнить тестовую систему coursera. Там лимиты для C++ - 1 секунда, а для python - 5 секунд.

Answer (score 5):

Так как в задаче есть ограничение на элементы массива:

> массивов натуральных чисел, каждое из которых не превосходит 100.

то можно применить [сортировку подсчётом](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC), которая работает за линейное время.

Но для C# возникает ещё одна проблема - это создание массива строк при считывании данных, которые на больших данных используют > 10Мб памяти. Я решила эту проблему с помощью запуска сборщика мусора.
Моё решение:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            short[] digitsCount = new short[101];
            short k = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            string[] values;
            for (short i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                values = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

                for (short j = 1; j < values.Length; j++)
                {
                    digitsCount[Convert.ToByte(values[j])]++;
                }

                GC.Collect();
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
            {
                for (short i = 0; i < digitsCount.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (short j = 0; j < digitsCount[i]; j++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(i + " ");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Удачи на собеседовании!

Comment: Это нерабочее решение. Оно сразу отваливается по ограничению времени

Answer (score 3):

В задаче не оговорен запрет на использование стандартной библиотеки, поэтому моё решение выглядит следующим образом (для Python 3.4.3):

```
from collections import Counter

k = int(input())
a = Counter()
for _ in range(k):
    a += Counter(map(int, input().split()[1:]))
for key, c in sorted(a.items()):
    print("{} ".format(key) * c, end="")
```

Ключевой момент здесь в том, что элементы в вводимых массивах не могут быть больше 100, а это значит, что количество ключей для Counter() не превысит это число. Даже в худшем случае, сортировка сотни целочисленных значений - простая задача. 
Опасения у меня вызывал только момент с суммированием Counter(), однако даже в последнем тесте, данный вариант затратил <5 mb памяти и уложился во время <0.7секунды.

Answer (score 2):

Сложность k * n

Time Limit помогло убрать периодический вывод буфера, а не накопление его до N

```py
k = int(input())

count = {str(i): 0 for i in range(100)}

total = 0
for list_index in range(k):
    a = input().split()
    size = int(a[0])
    total += size
    if size > 0:
        for i in range(1, size + 1):
            count[a[i]] += 1

buff = []
for i in range(100):
    c = str(i)
    if i % 10 and buff:
        print(' '.join(buff), end=' ')
        buff = []

    buff.extend([c] * count[c])

print(' '.join(buff))
```

Тест list + int() vs dict vs Counter

```
from timeit import timeit
from collections import Counter

n = 10000000
str_list = [str(x) for x in range(n)]

number = 10
print(timeit("""
for i in range(n):
    a[int(str_list[i]) % 100] += 1
""", setup='a = [0] * 100', number=number, globals=globals()))

print(timeit("""
for i in range(n):
    d[str_list[i % 100]] += 1
""", setup='d = {str(i): 0 for i in range(100)}', number=number, globals=globals()))


print(timeit("""
for i in range(n):
    d[str_list[i % 100]] += 1
""", setup='d = Counter(i for i in range(100))', number=number, globals=globals()))
```

PyPy 3.5.3 (не понятно, почему Яндекс его не добавили):

```
6.919497203998617
1.7934346760011977
5.253608144004829
```

Python 3.7

```
27.728900675007026
17.81548438500613
25.83648096800607
```

Comment: А зачем работать со словарём со строковыми ключами, если можно `count = [0]*100`

Comment: Данные изначально это строки, для листа пришлось бы делать N раз int(a[i]), что дороже чем найти в dict по ключу значение без преобразвания str > int. Добавил в ответ тесты

Comment: Так ведь dict будет это делать N раз, преобразуя строки в ключи. Впрочем, что в Python оптимальнее - трудно сказать. Upd: увидел тесты

Comment: Доступ к элементу в hash table это O(1), хотя оверхед поболее чем доступ по индексу листа.

Comment: Доступ да, но преобразование строки в ключ занимает время, вот мне и удивительно было, что это получилось быстрее int()

Comment: У нас всего 100 строк, а строки immutable, по идее 100 раз только хеш рассчитается.

Comment: Разные объекты-строки с одинаковым содержимым будут кэшироваться подобно byte в Java?

Comment: В Java для разных объектов с одинаковыми строками 2 раза будет хеш вычисляться, по-крайней мере дебагер мне это сказал на таком примере https://gist.github.com/AlexFedorovSWE/86214bc6c942b2c68d579a2c620d6ccb

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с этой задачей. Начал с Python 3.6. Пробовал сортировку подсчетом и heapq.merge. Ни в какую не укладываюсь в 1 секунду на 20м тесте. Попробовал переписать на Go и сортировку подсчетом. Результат по времени абсолютно такой же как на Python. Видимо от языка не зависит.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    const k = 100

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    arraysNumString, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    arraysNumString = strings.TrimSuffix(arraysNumString, "\n")

    arraysNum, err := strconv.Atoi(arraysNumString)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var counter [k]int

    for i := 0; i < arraysNum; i++ {
        inputString, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        inputString = strings.TrimSuffix(inputString, "\n")

        inputArray := strings.Split(inputString, " ")

        for idx, i := range inputArray {
            if idx == 0 {
                continue
            }
            j, err := strconv.Atoi(i)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            counter[j]++
        }
    }

    for index, value:= range counter {
        for i := 0; i < value; i++ {
            fmt.Println(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Видимо нужно искать другой алгоритм или экономить на чтении строк.

Comment: Вообще-то это не ответ, а выражение солидарности с автором вопроса. Я не буду голосовать ни за, не против, оставляя это на усмотрение сообщества. Просто на заметку - ответ должен содержать решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Реализация решения H. Case на основе встроенных типов.
Результаты - 0.522s, 4.36Mb.

```
n = int(input())

def counter_add(counter, value):
    if value in counter:
        counter[value] += 1
    else:
        counter[value] = 1

counter = dict()
for _ in range(n):
    ar = input().split()
    for i in ar[1:]:
        counter_add(counter, i)

for i in range(101):
    i = str(i)
    if i in counter:
        print(' '.join([i] * counter[i]), end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решила вот так - по-простому:

```
k=int(input())

result={x:0 for x in range(0,101)}

for i in range(k):

    current=input().split()[1:]

    for j in range(len(current)):
        cj = int(current[j])
        result[cj] += 1

for key, v in result.items():
    print("{} ".format(key) * v, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

А я решил пойти путем использования одномерных векторов. Жаль, что Я **не принял** импорт NumPy... Пришлось тоже через сортировку подсчетом делать. Надеюсь, будет полезно и на такой вариант взглянуть.

```
import sys
import numpy as np


k = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
A = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)

for _ in range(int(k)):
    line = np.array(sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" ")[1:], dtype=np.uint8)
    A = np.append(A, line)
    del line

A = np.sort(A, kind="mergesort")
A = A.tolist()
print(*A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой результат:
[image: Личной мой результат]

Код С++ 11 / (C++ 14):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ifstream file("input.txt");

    int k, kn, number;
    file >> k;

    // В карте запоминаем число, и сколько раз оно повторяется
    // Потом выводим несколько раз одно и тоже число
    // map дает автоматическую сортировку
    map<int, int> mmap;

    // Read from files
    while (k--) {
        file >> kn;
        while (kn--) {
            file >> number;
            ++mmap[number];
        }
    }

    file.close();


    ofstream file_out("output.txt");

    for (auto mpair: mmap) {
        while (mpair.second--) {
            file_out << mpair.first << " ";
        }
    }

    file_out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

ЗЫ. На питоне можно применить OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

Решение на python, на последнем тесте 0.81с, 3.89МБ. Сортировка подсчетом

```py
import sys
from collections import Counter


def read_int():
    return int(sys.stdin.readline())


def read_array():
    return list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))[1:]


def main():
    n = read_int()
    c = Counter()
    for _ in range(n):
        c += Counter(read_array())
    for i in sorted(c.keys()):
        print(" ".join(str(i) for _ in range(c[i])), end=' ')
```